# Bash Process Substitution does not work as 'root' on OS X

Tags: bash, shell, osx, root

OS X 10.6.8, if I use Bash Process Substitution as 'root', it just doesn't work.

- Is it supposed to be so?
- Why?

Note: here's what I mean... "<(list)"

```
mysql -D robottinosino < <(echo 'select robot from tino_sino;')
```

/* a contrived example, admittedly, as you could swap the echo and mysql using a simple pipe... I could not think of a better one off the top of my head */

EDIT:

- I am logging on as root like so:

  "sudo su -"

(incidentally, is there a better way if I want to *stay* logged on?)

- I am *not* on Bash so my question is really stupid and the comment below caught the problem instantly! :(

echo $0 yields "-sh" :(

I guess this question could just be deleted at this point or metamorphosed into:

"how to I properly log in as 'root' using bash?" (perhaps editing /private/etc/passwd? that does not seem to work. or... sudo bash -l?)

Comment: You don't log in using a shell of your choice, the system runs the shell specified for that user. That said, `sudo bash` or `su -c bash` is the closest you get to logging in using a shell. The shell is in `passwd` as a per-user setting of the shell to run when the user logs in (and you can change that, either by hand or using some tool for user settings management).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to change the shell, run `chsh -s /bin/bash`

If you want to run the shell once while logged in as root just run `bash` or `/bin/bash`

`chsh` after changing roots shell:

```
# Changing user information for root.
# Use "passwd" to change the password.
##
# Open Directory: /Local/Default
##
Login: root
Uid [#]: 0
Gid [# or name]: 0
Generated uid: FFFFEEEE-DDDD-CCCC-BBBB-AAAA00000000
Home directory: /var/root
Shell: /bin/bash
Full Name: System Administrator
Office Location:
Office Phone:
Home Phone:
```

Comment: Seems that bash is a standard binary on my OSX system, but I may be incorrect, double check your path.

Comment: I don't know about OS X, but some systems use a statically-linked `sh` as root's shell so that it can run during a recovery boot even if libraries aren't available (eg. on an unmounted `/usr` filesystem). See also, the `toor` account: http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/faq/security.html#TOOR-ACCOUNT

Comment: I must comment that I tried editing /etc/passwd and replacing /bin/sh to a path to bash but it got ignored... (possibly /etc/passwd is not how a shell is selected on OS X?)

Comment: @Robottinosino check my output above, it is stored in open directory. /etc/passwd is there for other reasons.

Comment: It's interesting that I am running "chsh -l /opt/local/bin/bash" as root, trying to point to MacPort's bash version, which I prefer as it has the v4's bashisms, and I get: chsh: Unable to open Directory node with name /opt/local/bin/bash.  Node name wasn't found.

Comment: @Robottinosino that is the incorrect syntax. Do `chsh -l /Local/Default -s /opt/local/bin/bash` or just `chsh -s /opt/local/bin/bash` will suffice.

Comment: I see. I screwed up the syntax then. Thanks.

Comment: BTW, this "trick" to change the shell for root on OS X was very useful to me, thanks a lot for suggesting it Tim, if I could upvote twice I would!

Comment: Glad to help sir :)

Answer (score 3):

If you are not using bash, you can't use that bash feature.

You could start using `sudo bash` to go root instead, or `sudo bash -l` to go root with a login shell, to read bash configuration.

Comment: You can also change `root`'s shell to the `bash`, or just invoke it when logged in as root (shells are just programs, you can launch a shell from inside a shell (*just* run `bash`), the only thing that happens is that when you leave it you're back to the shell you launched `bash` from)

Comment: I avoided suggesting changing the shell. Some systems default to `sh` for recovery shells, in particular systems where they include a statically-linked `sh` in `/bin`, and libraries might be unavailable during recovery (eg. because they're on unmounted filesystems like `/usr`).

Comment: I want my switching to root to be an interactive login in all effects (e.g. on OS X, reading .profile in preference to .bashrc...) Will your solution do this?

Comment: Ah, no, you'd need to use `sudo bash -l` for that. A little awkward, unfortunately.

Comment: Actually, sudo bash -l does look like an interactive login, does read root's .profile BUT... it keeps $HOME as /Users/robottinosino rather than /var/root?!

Comment: +1 this answer helps lead to the root cause of the problem OP specifies.